# What is the optimal start base location?

Tags: xenonauts

At the beginning of a game, Xenonauts lets you choose the location of your first base.

I started on the most Northern point of North Africa with the consideration that I can cover all of Europe and large parts of Africa and Asia from there.

However, most events seemed to occur in North America and Russia in the beginning. Also, I did not take into account that you can upgrade the reach of your base later.

1. **What factors should one consider when setting up your first base?**
2. **Is there an optimal location to start at, and if so, where is it?**

Answer (score 7):

Somewhere that can cover the most continents efficiently, like turkey as that covers russa, asia, europe and africa.

Comment: Agreed. You basically want to cover a decent swath of as many countries as possible. I like Central America as a location for a second base, as it also hits a lot of territory, but since it covers more water (and thus has less recoverable UFO missions) I agree that Turkey or near it works best.

Comment: I usually pic Crete as my first base as you cover most of Europe and still get large swaths of N.Africa, and Asia.

Comment: A little more to the West - Algeria or such. Otherwise you'll get an overlap with your third base (Indonesia).

Answer (score 3):

- First base: Saudi Arabia (east coast of the Red Sea). After 3 radars are built, it effectively covers 95% of Africa and 95% of Europe, plus a big chunk of Asia. Also 80% of the covered area is land.
- Second: Cuba.
- Third: Somewhere in Indochina to cover Australia as well.

Answer (score 0):

I put my first base in Crete (I called it Firebase Minotaur), it gives pretty good coverage of North Africa, all of Europe/Middle East and the Western half of the Soviet Union.

My second base I set up in Cuba (Firebase Castro) and gives good coverage of the Americas save for the far north and most of Argentina.

I set up a third base in Japan (Sword Airbase) to cover the rest of Asia and the Eastern half of Russia as well as some of the Polynesian islands.